# Two dataframe of yearly data how to find inbetween years

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, lambda

I have a python problem

```
df_2021 = pd.DataFrame([(10,20),(30,250),(50,60)], columns=['Toronto','Hamilton'])
df_2026 = pd.DataFrame([(100,200),(300,400),(500,600)], columns=['Toronto','Hamilton'])
```

I have two dataframe like this.  I am trying to find values for the inbetween years ie (2022, 2023, 2024, 2025).   I have to report on yearly numbers so these have to be integers.

How can I extrapolate this efficiently, with no rounding errors and keeping int

Answer (score 1):

`np.linspace` does that directly

```
>>> np.linspace(df_2021, df_2026, 6) # 6 because we have 6 years

array([[[ 10.,  20.],
        [ 30., 250.],
        [ 50.,  60.]],

       [[ 28.,  56.],
        [ 84., 280.],
        [140., 168.]],

       [[ 46.,  92.],
        [138., 310.],
        [230., 276.]],

       [[ 64., 128.],
        [192., 340.],
        [320., 384.]],

       [[ 82., 164.],
        [246., 370.],
        [410., 492.]],

       [[100., 200.],
        [300., 400.],
        [500., 600.]]])
```

To get a list of dataframes, just

```
my_dfs = [pd.DataFrame(x, columns=['Toronto','Hamilton']) for x in np.linspace(df_2021, df_2026, 6)]
```

---

Notice that [`linspace`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) has been only updated to work with non-scalar inputs from version 1.16.0 onwards

Comment: is there anyway to output them in dataframes?

Comment: @ReeseFitzmaurice just access each item..I've edited

Comment: Seems like an excellent idea, just that it's not working and throw `ValueError: The truth value...` on my system: numpy 1.15.4, pandas 0.24.2

Comment: @QuangHoang funny, I ran in numpy `'1.16.4'` and definitely runs !

Comment: @QuangHoang Just saw in docs, it works from `1.16` onwards ;) Might wanna try a solution for numpy < 1.16?

Comment: is there anyway to do it without listing the columns, because i have a lot of them

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that should work for lower version of numpy:

```
(pd.DataFrame({2021: df_2021.stack(),
              2026: df_2026.stack()})
   .reindex(range(2021,2027), axis=1)
   .interpolate(axis=1)
   .astype(int)
)
```

gives

```
            2021  2022  2023  2024  2025  2026
0 Toronto     10    28    46    64    82   100
  Hamilton    20    56    92   128   164   200
1 Toronto     30    84   138   192   246   300
  Hamilton   250   280   310   340   370   400
2 Toronto     50   140   230   320   410   500
  Hamilton    60   168   276   384   492   600
```